# Proguard warnings about duplicate class definitions, but doesn't print out the duplicate classes

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I'm trying to change the version of a library in my app, but I think I'm getting some kind of conflicts with another version of some dependency that another library I'm using is trying to use. It warns me about duplicate class definitions, but then goes on only to print out specific examples of the next warning category (in this case unresolved class definitions).

```
...
:RedactedApp:proguardDebug
Note: there were 644 duplicate class definitions (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Warning: redacted.package.ClassName: can't find superclass or interface other.redacted.package.ClassName2
...
...
Warning: there were 12 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
     You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
     If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
     the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
     (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 5 unresolved references to library class members.
     You probably need to update the library versions.
     (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
```

Is there a way to force proguard to actually print out the names of detected duplicate classes? I already have -verbose enabled in my proguard file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I couldn't find a way to get proguard to actually print out the duplicate classes, I was able to get a good view of dependencies via a gradle (2.9) command:

```
gradle -q dependencies :RedactedAppName:dependencies --configuration compile
```

This gave me a good graphical view of a lot of redundant imports I had.